# Jenkins Job children not been killed with pkill -P

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jenkins

I am trying to kill a Jenkins job and all of it's children through command line. Job itself just runs a script.

So I look for it:

```
ps aux | grep jenkins
```

Then kill it:

```
pkill -P PID
```

However in the script there is `pg_dump` command and it seems that it is still running:

```
ps aux | grep pg_dump

postgres  8287  8.1  0.0 168476  4940 ?        S    19:01   0:41 pg_dump -O db_name
```

Is this some kind of residual? What am I missing here?

Thanks s bunch.

Comment: does the same thing happen when you kill the build through the jenkins UI? i assume so, but the answer to this question might help to differentiate a "jenkins issue" from a "postgres issue."

Comment: @KevinBurnett from Jenkins UI it's the same thing.